# CSS - HTML Lists - center UL in page & left align LI items

Tags: css, alignment, html-lists

I have this code:

```css
.menu {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
    background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
  <li class="item">8</li>
  <li class="item">9</li>
  <li class="item">10</li>
</ul>
```

I want to center align the entire `ul` container, while keeping the `li` items aligned to left.

So instead of this:

[image]

I want to have something like this:

[image]

I can't seem to make it work..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found, which still allowed the entire UL to take as much as possible from the browser width (for responsiveness) while still centered, was with:

```
ul.menu {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: {x}px
}
```

and using `@media` queries to set the perfect width for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following flex box solution:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
  background: green;
}

.item {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vw;
  background: red;
  margin: 1vw;
  /*the following is only for styling the numbers*/
  font-size: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
  <li class="item">8</li>
  <li class="item">9</li>
  <li class="item">10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the container (UL) centered

Comment: Centered with respect to what? The `body`?

Comment: Currently, my `ul` takes up the entire width of the page, but  wait, let me update that

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I mean. It should not take the entire width of the page, WITHOUT manually setting a width.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm trying to find a solution without setting the `width: 80vw;`, so it will take as much space as possible to show as much as possible items per row.

Comment: the space between the UL left/right border to the items should be equal

Comment: the space was to display the right alignment. If the spacing between the items have to be equal, then your requirement of "while keeping the li items aligned to left" is rather pointless

Comment: No. it's not pointless, in terms of design. this way the items will be relativly as a block centered exactly in screen, while still keeping new items in new row aligned to left

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.menu {
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
width: 500px; /* Change this value is you need more li in the same line. You can also use percents */
/*width: 90% */
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
.item {
width: 60px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 4em;
background-color:red;
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
padding: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pixels with .item, I think this will suites best:

```
.menu {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Basically i just added measurements for the UL element. 
Hope i helped and Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try surounding you  element in div (or whatever else) with display: flex. Margin: auto property only works on flex.