# How can I center content

Tags: css

How can I center all the contents in the page, and make the order be right-to-left, because the alignment is to the left and the order is left to right.

here is the code:

**Edit**
Center parent div

[image]

```css
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 270px;
  min-height: 260px;
  max-height: 260px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 5px #bfbbd9;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>4</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: as one group ,the image above will show more.

Comment: Yusuf, that's happening in the current setup... Can you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- set the `parent-div` to be with fixed width and centered using `margin: 0 auto`.
- use `direction: rtl` and `text-align: right` on `parent-div` to align items to right with your desired direction.
- change grid item to be `display:inline-block` instead of using `float`
- add media queries if you want it to have more columns on heigher screen resolutions.

```css
.parent-div {
   width: 592px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   direction: rtl;
   text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
   .parent-div {
      width: 890px
   }
}

.grid-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 270px;
  min-height: 260px;
  max-height: 260px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 5px #bfbbd9;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>4</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div style="height:71px">
        <h2>5</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

EDIT: I have added one step for media query as example for 3 columns in heigher screen resolutions. you can run the code snippet in full screen to see the result.

Comment: If I remove the float, two columns will be displayed, and I want to use it in responsive web pages, so when the big shack will stretch

Comment: I've been there this week (my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492844/css-html-lists-center-ul-in-page-left-align-li-items). My solution finally was similar to what I suggested here with media queries for the parent container width for different screen sizes. or.. if you want, you can achieve this using bootstrap grid on the grid items: "col-md-xs-4 col-md-sm-3 col-md-2" and probably with css tweaks for your grid-item.

Comment: Currently there is no way in css for the parent-div to wrap the inline-block elements and to be centered using margin:0 auto. it will always will take 100% of the page width.. so media queries is your only option. (with or without using some existing grid)

Comment: @Yusuf I have edited the answer with an example for media query

Answer (score 0):

Try using `inline-block` for `display` and remove `float`. That should work out.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 3px;
}
.grid-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 270px;
  min-height: 260px;
  max-height: 260px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 5px #bfbbd9;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div style="height:71px">
      <h2>1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div style="height:71px">
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div style="height:71px">
      <h2>4</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div style="height:71px">
      <h2>5</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div style="height:71px">
      <h2>6</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

**Preview** in different resolutions:

**Mobile**

[image: mobile]

**Tablet / iPad**

[image: ipad]

**Desktop**

[image: desktop]